# 32 TB RAID... Should I use 5 or 6?

Tags: raid

A friend directed me here for this question.

I am putting together a RAID.  It will be composed of 4 8TB drives and I am trying to decide what RAID level to use.

Originally I was going to go with RAID 5 but I have been reading that with that much storage RAID 5 can be a bit risky.  So I was wondering what you all would do.

A bit about the data and how it will be used:

1. It is very expensive data so it must be safe.
2. Write speed is not super important.  Data will rarely be written but it will be written in huge chunks.  Like several TBs at a time.  So while it would suck if the write speed is terrible, we wouldn't have to deal with that problem very often.
3. Read speed is very important.  Large amounts of data will be accessed at once.

So it seems like RAID 6 is the way to go.... but I am just wondering how dangerous RAID 5 really is with a RAID this size.  What is everyone's experience?  How likely is it for me to need dual parity protection?  If it is a huge risk, then I am willing to deal with the awful write speed and loss of 8TB of space.  But if this is just an overly cautious sort of thing I would rather go with RAID 5.

What do you all think?  RAID 5 or RAID 6?  Also is there another RAID level that might fit my needs better?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think you should use RAID 10. It also sounds like you're not planning on having backups.  RAID is not a backup.

Comment: So it was my understanding that RAID 10 still only protects against one drive failure.  If you have a URE on the second drive in the rebuilding of the nested RAID 1 you are still toast right?

Is the benefit simply that you would only have to read one drive for rebuild instead of three?  Effectively cutting chances of URE in a third?  Am I doing this math/ understanding how this works right?

Comment: RAID 10. 5 and 6 are long dead

Comment: RAID 10 will protect against 50% drive failure in a four disk configuration. It's a stripe of mirrors, capable of losing one drive per mirror. However, this means that you may only lose one drive per mirror for a total of two, rather than any drive in the array for a total of two as is the case in RAID 6. RAID5/6 rebuild time is trash and gobbles iops, so consider that. Also, a degraded RAID 10 will perform fine, whereas degraded RAID5/6 will perform badly, even when not rebuilding.

Comment: Would anyone recommend RAID 50 for this large array?

Answer (score 3):

Any data you don't want to lose should be stored in more than one location. RAID is no substitute for backup, so make sure you store a backup in another location.

One important difference between a backup and a mirror is that a backup will still be there even if the original is deleted. If you delete any of your original files, the mirrored files will be deleted as well.

With a proper backup the RAID is just there to reduce the frequency of events that will require you to restore the data from backup.

The best RAID level for your usage depends on both access patterns and the size of your data. RAID5 will be faster than RAID6 in pretty much all usage scenarios, and RAID5 will give you more storage capacity. All of this comes at the cost of higher risk of losing data.

But if your data is small enough to fit on a single disk, you could choose to use RAID1 with four replicas. With a replica on each of the four disks, the risk of data loss due to hardware faults will be tiny. RAID1 will give you good performance for random access reads. But for writes and sequential reads the RAID1 will be slower than RAID5 or RAID6.

Answer (score 2):

You don't know what state your data is in until you do a full rebuild, hence if you lose a sector or 2 on a single drive then another drive fails you will lose all your data using raid5.  Raid6 will likely recover in this scenario. But, as yoonix says you've offerred nothing to support a choice between raid6 and raid10.

Comment: I guess I never considered RAID 10 because it still only covers one drive failure.  But I suppose the chances are lower of URE?

Comment: A primary consideration in your choice of raid is the workload pattern - large/small/sequential/random

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by workload pattern.  Forgive my naivety in this subject.